# How to get number of rows affected by an update query to unix ksh script?

Tags: unix, ksh

How to return number of rows affected by an update query to unix ksh script?

Here is my code

```
RETVAL=`sqlplus -s $ConnectionString <<EOF
SET PAGESIZE 0 FEEDBACK ON VERIFY OFF HEADING OFF ECHO OFF
update table1 set stat=1 where position=10;
EXIT;
EOF`
```

As i set the `FEEDBACK ON` i get `1 rows affected` value in RETVAL. Is it possible to get the numeric value 1 in RETVAL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just take the string "1 rows affected", split it by the first space and take the left part

```
affectedLines=${RETVAL%% *}
```